# Can I combine provider hosted app and spfx app in a single app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spfx-extensions

I am building a product which is available in both version of SharePoint online i.e. Modern as well as classic view. I have developed provider hosted app as well as spfx app, now the problem is that client has to install both the app separately so is it possible to have a single app for both provider hosted app as well as spfx app. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

They're different architecture, provider hosted add-in(app) contains a remote component(a web app usually), if you have add-in part in your provider-hosted add-in, it's render as iframe while spfx webpart is rendered as normal DOM inside a page.

[Check official documentation for more details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview#why-the-sharepoint-framework)

You may migrate your add-in part to SPFx webpart based on your actual scenario.

Comment: I cannot migrate add-in part to SPFx as remote event receiver is not available in SPFx. So is there any way to bundle SPFx and add-in(app)? So that client does not have to it separately.